# List IPs line by line with bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I need list of IPs by `dig` command I'm using bash script but some of domain like google.com have many IPs I need only one result

```
#!/bin/bash
while read domain; do
ipaddr=$(dig +short $domain)
echo -e  "$ipaddr" >> results.csv
done < domainlist.txt
```

output ( if we take google an example )

```
173.194.35.101
173.194.35.102
173.194.35.96
173.194.35.110
173.194.35.98
173.194.35.100
173.194.35.99
173.194.35.104
173.194.35.103
173.194.35.97
173.194.35.105
```

I need only the first line

Comment: `head -1` gets the first line.

Comment: Just what @fedorqui said is: `ipaddr=$(dig +short $domain | head -1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read domain; do
ipaddr=$(dig +short $domain | head -1)
echo -e  "$ipaddr" >> results.csv
done < domainlist.txt
```

Check if this is ok.

```
ipaddr=$(dig +short $domain | head -1)
```

Piping through `head -1` should return the first ip from the list of ip.s returned by `dig` command.

Comment: That is what he/she expects i guess. He/she wants 1 IP for each domain according to my understanding.

Comment: Thanks every one yes i need only one ip for each

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it through `head` :

```
ipaddr=$(dig +short $domain | head -n 1)
```